# Configuring android app installed in arc welder

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I have installed coding calendar android app in chrome using arc welder in my windows.It gives the information about running and future coding contest depending on location and time.I live in India, so I like to see contests according to that.But this app is showing America/Los_Angeles(As seen in the image link).http://tinypic.com/r/2a69mbl/8
So Please help me how to install that app correctly so that location is India.
should I add anything in metadata?

Comment: Please show the code where you are displaying "the information about running and future coding contest depending on location and time". Where are you getting the time zone information from? After all, ARC Welder is only for developers, so you must be the developer of this app, and Stack Overflow needs a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code to help you determine where things are going wrong.

Comment: that is included in the image(Timezone: America...)

Comment: "that is included in the image" -- your Java source code is not included in the image. Please post your Java source code that is generating this UI.

Comment: sorry, Iam not developer. I just want to use this app as I don't have android phone.